# How do I calculate the number of months between two dates in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns on Microsoft Excel:  F is the column with the date service ended; E is the column with the date service began.

How do I calculate and report the number of months served for each person?

Comment: Please tell us the desired result with  (e.g) 14.3.2014 - 12.7.2014: (a) 4 months (the 4th is not complete) or (b) 5 months (counting every touched month) or (c) 3 months (only complete months count) or (d) 3.9 months.

Comment: Answer here is better than 'original' linked in this question

Answer (score 16):

DATEDIF function explicitly gives you the number of months between two dates - it rounds down

`=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"m")`

where A2 is the earlier of the two dates

If you want to round to the "nearest" whole month you can use this version

`=DATEDIF(A2,B2+15,"m")`

If you don't care about the day and any date in Jan to any date in March is 3 months then you can use this version

`=DATEDIF(A2-DAY(A2)+1,B2,"m")+1`

Comment: Works on Google Sheets as well.

Comment: You can use `=(B2 - A1)/(365/12)` if you want a non-rounded answer, it considers a month being on average 365/12 days long

Answer (score 3):

There is a KB from Microsoft covering this very topic [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214134)

It provides two solutions, depending if you want to round the months down or up.

Round up:

```
=(YEAR(LDate)-YEAR(EDate))*12+MONTH(LDate)-MONTH(EDate)
```

Round down:

```
=IF(DAY(LDate)>=DAY(EDate),0,-1)+(YEAR(LDate)-YEAR(EDate))*12+MONTH(LDate)-MONTH(EDate)
```

In both cases EDate is the cell containing the earlier date, and LDate is the cell containing the later.